# Extract a WPF content template of a running WPF application

Tags: wpf, templates, runtime, extract

is there a way of extracting a content template of a WPF control which is hosted in a running WPF application?

Just the same way as I am able to dig through the visual tree of any WPF application with tools like Snoop I'd like to be able to extract the Content Template.

I have asked Google already. But either my keywords were totally wrong or there might be no solution (what I doubt).

Could please someone give me a hint?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What do yo think about that small extension method?

```
using XamlWriter = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter;
public static class FrameworkTemplateExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns properly-indented XAML representing the given template.
    /// </summary>
    public static string AsXaml(this FrameworkTemplate template)
    {
        if (template == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlSettings.Indent = true;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, xmlSettings))
        {
            XamlWriter.Save(template, writer);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Template is defined in Xaml, which ends up as Binary Xaml (Baml), which is going to make it much harder, if not impossible, to get the Template in Xaml format decompiled.

Comment: Mhm.. wouldn't have expected it to be impossible to get the template as Reflector for example doesn't have too many issues with resolving plain XAML out of BAML.

Answer (score 0):

This tool allows you to view the running WPF tree.  So long as you aren't debugging the application with VS at the same time.

http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/